# Duplicating name characters in java?

Tags: java, string, loops

so i'm trying to make a program that will let the user input his/her name. then print out the characters of their name depending on what position it is in.

Example.

```
Enter your name : Joshua
Output : Joossshhhhuuuuuaaaaaa               //multiplying the characters of their names.
```

So here is my code im pretty far cause, im not very familiar with the String Methods yet.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 class Namex {
 public static void main(String[]args) {

  Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);

  String name = "";
  int z;



   System.out.print("Enter name : ");
   name = x.nextLine();

     y = name.length()-1;

    for(int i=0; i<=y; i++) {        //i'm not quite sure what method to use yet 

    }

   }                       // should i use charAt?
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your 'for' loop you can place  this 'for loop' to print. You should use 'charAt(k)' to get character of k'th position.

```
for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
    System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: your code works actually when i placed it inside the for loop

Comment: @Jake yes, this code should works inside your existing for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String multiplyLetters(String text) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        for (int count = 0; count < i + 1; ++count) {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

class name 
 {

public static void main(String[]args) 
 {
   Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter name : ");

    String name = x.nextLine();



   for(int i=1; i<=name.length(); i++) 
   {
       for(int s=0;s<i;s++)
     {
           System.out.print(name.charAt(i-1));
                        }//End nested for
     }//End main for

System.out.println();

}//End Main

 }//End Class
```